# Viewpager Lineindicator not working for large data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to impliment a viewpager with line indicator using fragment.if     item number is 10 i can swipe viewpager and can show indicator,but f the item 
 number is more than 10 cant see indicator,its out of the screen..can any one
 help me?

```
XPagerAdapter xPagerAdapter = new XPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), items);
    xViewPager.setAdapter( xPagerAdapter );

    LinePageIndicator indicator = (LinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator1);
    indicator.setViewPager(xViewPager);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    indicator.setSelectedColor(Color.BLACK);
    indicator.setUnselectedColor(Color.GRAY);
    indicator.setStrokeWidth(4 * density);
    indicator.setLineWidth(20 * density);
    indicator.setMinimumHeight((int) (8 * density));
    indicator.setCentered(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library for this instead. Take a look at [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator).